# std::unordered_map constructor with initializer_list and size compiles in main, but not in class definition

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, unordered-map, list-initialization

I am trying to initialize an `std::unordered_map` using the constructor that accepts data through an initialization list and the initial number of buckets.

For some reason, that constructor works if I put it in `main`, but has a syntax error when I put it in a class header.

Specifically, the header, called `momo.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <unordered_map>

namespace std 
{
   template <>
   struct hash<std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t>>
   {
      std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t>& k) const
      {
         return (std::hash<long>()((((long)k.first) << 16) + (long)k.second));
      }
   };
}

class test
{
   std::unordered_map<std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t>, uint16_t> m_Z(
      { /* Fails here: syntax error: missing ')' before '{' */
          {std::pair{ 1, 2 }, 3},
          {std::pair{ 4, 5 }, 6}
      }, 128);

};
```

While if I remove the definition from the header into `main` thus:

```
#include "Momo.h"

int main()
{
   test X;

   std::unordered_map<std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t>, uint16_t> Y(
      {
          {std::pair{ 1, 2 }, 3},
          {std::pair{ 4, 5 }, 6}
      }, 128);
}
```

The code compiles without error. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to  [braced-init-list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)(or uniform-initiation) the `std::unordered_map` in the class.

```
class test
{
   std::unordered_map<std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t>, uint16_t> m_Z{ // >> brased init
      { 
           {std::pair{ 1, 2 }, 3},
           {std::pair{ 4, 5 }, 6}
      }, 128 
   }; // >>>

};
```

Comment: This works for me (will mark it as an answer in a few minutes, when the site allows me), which raises the question why?

Comment: @UriRaz That is the only way(or also with `map ={}`) you can initialize it in the class definition. Read More:https://blog.quasardb.net/2017/03/05/cpp-braced-initialization